# Being a "tattletale" at work

Tags: professionalism, company-culture, politics

I feel like there is a very strong culture of everyone telling on everyone else in the workplace, especially in places that practice frequent one on ones.

Is it just me, or is this a rotten practice that destroys trust between coworkers? I was brought up to solve my own issues with my peers, in a culture where telling on someone was a sign of unfairness and underhandedness, and still carry it with me. Whenever I have an issue with coworkers, I try to work them out and not escalate anything to management as long as I can. However, it seems that management always magically knows of any issues, and obviously not from my perspective. Even things that don't concern others, like frequency of washroom breaks. And I'm a pretty senior employee in good tech companies, working alongside smart, educated people. As a team lead, I was expected to gossip and dig up dirt about my team. I no longer want to be a team lead.

Am I wrong to judge it such? How can I find likeminded companies and people, without seeming disloyal to management? Is this a cultural thing, and if so, which cultures have it more/less?

Comment: what are you asking here?

Comment: I think it's definitely a workplace culture thing.  I've worked in places where these sorts of shenanigans go on all the time, and I've worked in places where they don't.  The difference is night and day.  Unfortunately, I don't think there's a very good way to identify the good places in advance, except by networking and asking people who already work there or have worked there (ideally friends you already know you can trust.)

Comment: Would you also say it's unfair and underhanded to get the police or law involved to help you with dealing with a criminal? Of course when you decide to seek help will differ from person to person and culture to culture. A team lead is generally expected to give honest feedback to management regarding what happens in the team - that's part of their job. If that's what you're referring to when you say "gossip and dig up dirt", you should probably just stay out of management entirely. If you're referring to something else, you should probably clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a cultural thing for the company specifically.  Sure country and general culture may contribute to this, but each company culture has their own dynamics that are made up by the people in the company and the way the company is run.

The best way to detect this is not easy but doable.  When visiting and interviewing pay close attention to detail.  Ask questions about the various members of the team and see how the people respond.  If they respond with very professional comments about their team mates there is a better chance this is not the company culture.  If they respond with quirky stories that could be somewhat embarrassing or leaving you wondering what the inside story of that is, then it is likely a sign that they have a more gossiping culture.  I always hope they will say things like, they are a really good at doing (X - where x is part of their job).  Comments like kind, generous, etc... are good to hear and likely ambiguous, your looking for story level events that are missing both sides etc...  Basically if someone is willing to talk about someone else with details to a total stranger in an interview you can be certain they will do so in the office environment as well.

**Healthy Example**: Bob is a great programmer and is good a code reviews.  Sally does an excellent job as our Configuration Manager and keeps us all straight.  Jim knows alot and loves to help out his teammates with figuring out solutions to complex issues.

**Gossipy Example**: Bob is a great programmer, he loves popcorn, you should have smelled it the other day, it burned and stunk the whole place up.  Sally is our Configuration Manager, she really gets in the weeds and keeps us straight, can be annoying sometimes, but we all need correcting now and then.  Jim really knows alot and likes to share it with everyone, if he gets on your nerves tell him his opinions on your tasks are not wanted.

Gossipy environments will require management intervention on a frequent basis versus a more professional boundary and teamwork based environment.  Teamwork involves what you are saying with working things out as a team and only escalating when it can't be addressed as a team.